# Настройка Postgresql на мак

Tags: postgresql

После попытки удаления всех баз и пользователей
 пытаюсь заново настроить. Для этого пытаюсь войти сменить пароль суперюзера

Ввожу в консоли

```
 MacBook-Pro-Andrej:~ andrej$ sudo su - postgres
```

В ответ запрашивает пароль

Но какой пароль может быть, если в pb_hba.cfg у меня прописано следующее

```
 local    all     all                  trust
 # IPv4 local connections:
 host all all   127.0.0.1/32           trust
 # IPv6 local connections:
 host all all    ::1/128               trust

 local replication  all               trust
 host replication all 127.0.0.1/32    trust
 host replication all ::1/128         trust
```

В логе прописывает 
      FATAL: database "andrej" does not exist

Что весьма странно, поскольку до этого я удалял все базы...

Ладно, пытаюсь удалить базу "andrej" еще раз. Но, при попытке сделать это ( примеру, sudo -u postgres dropdb andrej), запрашивает пароль...

Comment: does not exist - переводится как не существует. Вы уже удалили базу.

Comment: sudo -u postgres dropdb andrej - пароль запрашивается для sudo

Comment: ах, дааа, точно

Answer (score 1):

проблема решилась, когда я переустановил postgresql.app